# No theme.css file found Codename One

Tags: codenameone

While I was coding my computer crashed, when I got back to my project and run the Simulator I got this message in console: `No theme.css file found.  CSSWatcher canceled` What does that mean? Is it something critical, how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not important at all. It's a new feature that we will announce soon, it's just a message that indicates it isn't active. I've removed it since it's irrelevant.

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine an empty theme editor also opens along the simulator, when I run the application and I am getting the error message CSS> WARNING: unspecified resource Application.id using ResourceEditorApp. When I run the jar I am getting the same above error message No theme.css file found.  CSSWatcher canceled. Is this also of temporary nature and related to the new feature?

Comment: Yes, it's not an error it's a warning. It shouldn't impact development. Right? Are you using the CSS plugin? If so we have some changes coming...

Comment: Shai, yes I am using the css plugin. Impacts development a little, since I have to wait every time for the simulator AND the theme editor to open. But if it helps in developing a better product, no problem to be patient. Great job you guys are doing, anyway. Love CN1  ...

Comment: I saw the problem and we pushed out a workaround for it. If you update the libs it should fetch the fix.